# Re-runnable db alter scripts

Tags: database, release

Is there a standard on db alter scripts (both data and ddl), should they be re-runnable if so what are the reasons for making them re-runnable.

The only web pages I could find are telling me how to do it, but i want to know why to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by re-runnable? Every script can be run multiple times, but each run may produce different results or even errors. If you mean scripts that don't have different effects when run a second time, that attribute is called Idempotence. It is most often used in APIs but can also be valuable in db scripts etc. Just look up the word online for many "why"s.

Comment: a script that produces errors when it is re run, is not re-runnable it is run once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you want to have re-runnable scripts is the same reason you want idempotent operations in any other situation in IT: to avoid *state*.

By "state", here we mean that the state of the world influences what the outcome of an operation will be. Idempotent operations have the same effect no matter what the state of the world is - other operations don't. State, for lack of a better world, is evil. It is the reason why an operation works in testing but fails in production, why my machine does something different with the same codebase than your machine, etc. etc. State adds complexity to systems in a field (IT) where complexity is already Public Enemy #1 and the root cause of most evil. Entire subfields, such as functional programming, have been invented predominantly to avoid state.

Why is it generally a good idea to avoid state? Because it's often not that much harder to write an operation in an idempotent way (e.g. using UPDATE OR INSERT rather than INSERT) than in the default way, and once you've done that, you can ignore one particular complication *completely*.

This is invaluable for dealing with complex systems. One of the methods we deal with complexity is compartmentalization; another is abstraction. Once you have abstracted away the difference between "a database in exactly this state" and "a database with this schema but an unknown state" and are able to deal with a database in *any* state, you no longer have to think about it *at all*, and that is a great help in solving a problem that already requires you to think about too many things at once to get to a solution.

Comment: thank you, I knew it was a good thing but just couldn't explain why to my collegues to change their practices. This is an excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

The idea of such a script is to take the database from one "known state" to another "known state".  You don't want to end up in some "half-way house", which would be even *more complicated* to sort out.

Some cases are easier to handle than others.

If, for example, you are adding a column to a table, then your script will *fail* if you try to run it a second time because the column already exists.  If your DBMS supports transactional DDL, then the whole thing rolls back - no harm, no foul.  If it doesn't, like Oracle, then you have to do something [a lot] more complicated.

If, for example, you are adding rows to a table, then your script really ought to check whether those rows exist *before* you do the insert(s).  If not, you could wind up with duplicated data that can cause *all sorts* of weird and wonderful "bugs" to crawl out of poorly-written (or naively-expectational) SQL.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes and" to the answers above.

1. If you're trying to run a zero-downtime deployment, you may want to avoid some transactions even if/when they're supported. Idempotent scripts provide some (not all) of the failure-proofing that transactions do without a major drawback: If I put a bunch of schema changes into a transaction, it's going to block some or all operations against those tables. Same may be true for large updates. If users are blocked for a noticeable amount of time, your app is effectively down as far as they're concerned.
2. You may *need* to run a migration more than once - consider the case of copying data from an "old" to a "new" schema. Again, if you're doing zero-downtime, users may still be inserting data into the "old" table *while your release is running*. You'll need to run this migration *after* the release to make sure those rows aren't lost (if not continuously *during* the release)
3. A minor and possibly opinionated one, but it makes life easier w.r.t. git merges. If you and I both rely on a column that doesn't exist yet, we don't have to merge or rebase our whole dang build scripts as long as we `if not exists`.